# Safari sending floated div to new line, chrome and IE are fine

Tags: firefox, safari, css-float

The situation:

**Parent div: 300px**

**Child 1: 50px width, 5 px border**

**Child 2: 232px width, 8px margin left**

Works fine in chrome and IE, but Safari and firefox drop the second one to the new line. Any reason for this? If I remove 1 px to the overall, like having a 7px left margin, they fit into place. Also, measurements match perfectly in firebug, so I don't see why thew two are not fitting in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all other padding or margin from Parent div and children. These are caused from default browser styles.  (or use CSS Reset to do this for all your elements)

Also, as a note, Safari and Opera are a little bit lying about measurements if you have a decimal number. They round up or down, they are not so exact like Firefox or Chrome.